# ajax control tool kit generates 100's of ScriptResource.axd

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, scriptresource.axd

ASP.net VS2008 .net3.5

I have been using the Ajax Control tool kit for years, and today I downloaded to latest version for 3.5.

the took kit works but generate 100's of line like this one

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/shs-vb/ScriptResource.axd?d=K-TRG1ZyD75GiB2qjZl-kxNm4m6VgRN…MESAcdMp6J32NsJhIAG9PEtl3ggamidSswF7NLGK0&t=ffffffffcda035a6"></script>
```

in the html code.

It happen last year but I have no recollection on how it was solved. 
It is something to do with updating.
I try to delete all references in the bin folder than add the reference again.
I removed and recreated the toolbox tab.

Is there an Reference to update in the web.config?
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: found it: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19710731/ajax-control-toolkit-is-loading-too-many-script-resources

Answer (score 1):

Set CombineScripts and ScriptMode properties for toolkit script manager control:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" CombineScripts="true" ScriptMode="Release" >
...
</ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

By default AjaxControlToolkit loads all scripts than it generate 100's of line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>
```

You can manage what scripts for what controls should be added by updating web.config

```
<ajaxControlToolkit>
  <controlBundles>
    <controlBundle>
        ...
    </controlBundle>
  </controlBundles>
</ajaxControlToolkit>
```

Comment: thanks, that works indeed, BUT It generates a new problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21165086/ajax-control-tool-kit-combining-script-vs-processing-time , Any idea how to solve this one.